# Repeated application of parameters from a stream to a fluent builder method

Tags: java, functional-programming, jax-rs, java-stream, purely-functional

I'm writing a REST service client using the Jax-RS. For a request I'd like to add query parameters. The according method in Jax-RS is `webTarget.queryParam(name, value)` returning a *new* WebTarget instance (so webtarget is immutable).

Further, I have a stream of name-value-pairs: `Stream<Tuple<String,String>> queryParams` with a varying number of elements.

Now I'd like to repeatedly apply the parameters from the stream to the `queryParam()` method, using the result as invocation target on the next application:

As rolled out invocation it would look like this:

```
WebTarget original = ...
WebTaragt wt1 = original.queryParam(t1.name,t1.value);
WebTaragt wt2 = wt1.queryParam(t2.name,t2.value);
...
WebTarget wtFinal = wtNminus1.queryParam(tN.name,tN.value);
```

Is there a way to *efficiently* implement this as pure function?

Comment: The overhead of streams starts to break even in the 10K+ range. In a rest request seems an overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not yet make a statement about the *efficiency*, but, you may want to look into [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). The following solution assumes that you have at least one `WebTarget` which you can use to carry out the reduction. Moreover I this solution doesn't allow parallelization (for that an appropriate combiner would be needed and I do not know how the `WebTarget`s need to be combined).

```
Stream<Tuple<String, String>> queryParamStream = ...
WebTarget wtFinal = queryParamStream.reduce(original,
                        (webtarget, tuple) -> webtarget.queryParam(tuple.name, tuple.value),
                        (webtarget1, webtarget2) -> /* what would be needed to combine those when you use a parallel stream? */ webtarget2);
```